# I keep losing my bitcoins

Tags: sending, lost-bitcoins

I have only just started using bitcoins but when I send them from my wallet they get lost and don't get to the other bitcoins address I can't understand it does anyone no  why this happens thanks

Comment: You can check out where your money went by pasting the address you sent them from into into the search field (the one in the middle of the website, not the one in the top) of https://blockchain.info/.

Comment: My bitcoins seem to have gone to the right addressees but they have not received them  is their anything else I can do or do or  you think I have lost them

Comment: If you can see that there are confirmations of that transaction on https://blockchain.info/, the money is now the receiver's. They may, however, have a connection issue with their client so their client doesn't show them that they have the money but they do.